# Three.js Morph Targets- Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'x' of undefined

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm trying to adapt this morph target example: http://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_morphtargets_human
with a custom model but i keep getting this "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'x' of undefined" on three.js:19472. The x variable is one of the morph target vertices, so i'm guessing when rendering it's having issues understanding the value.

I was wondering if someone can tell me if i'm missing something obvious I need to add to the code for this specific model as i haven't alterted anything but disabled the keyframe animations in the UCSCharacter script as i'm not using them.

Here's the Json model and build.
http://we.tl/yWzKiFmBdb

Comment: Have you done any debugging at all? Try commenting out lines of code to try and narrow down exactly what in your code is causing the problem.

Comment: Yes i did some debugging, the error code is coming from the library though and the code entirely from an example, the most i did was swap the model. I was orgininally working in threejs 71, after testing in 73 and dev i'm getting a warning instead of an error "THREE.BufferAttribute.copyVector3sArray(): vector is undefined 16087". Which is starting to make me believe the problem is in the vertices blender is exporting as motion targets in JSON no idea why though, the shape keys work fine in blender.